# How to kill conflicting process?

Tags: python, kivy, buildozer

My Kivy app is crashing on Android due to:

`CameraService: Conflicts with: Device 1, client package com.gad.kivyandroid (PID 13357, priority 2147483645)`

When I tried to run `os.kill(13357, SIGKILL)` this will kill the whole app not just the conflicting process.

What can I do ?

**Update:**

I've ran `ps` in adb shell to see what's the name of the process is so I can better target it. The service is called `cameraserver`. When I ran

```
pid_to_kill = check_output(['pidof', 'cameraserver'])
os.kill(int(pid_to_kill.decode().strip('\n')), SIGKILL)
```

it kills the whole app again, not just the conflicting camera process.

**Second Update:**

creating layout and xcamera instance:

```
self.xcamera_layout = FloatLayout(size=Window.size)
self.front_cam = XCamera(index=1, directory=path)
self.xcamera_layout.add_widget(self.front_cam)
self.add_widget(self.xcamera_layout)
```

and before switching to rear camera (I haven't tried to change `index=1` to `0` instead of killing the camera instance) I do this:

```
self.xcamera_layout.remove_widget(self.front_cam)
self.remove_widget(self.xcamera_layout)
del self.front_cam
del self.xcamera_layout
```

I'll try to simply switch index of camera lens instead of killing one camera instance and starting another.

Error output:

```
CameraService: CameraService::connect X (PID 29095) rejected (existing client(s) with higher priority)
```

I've tried so many different approaches to this problem but obviously the one that actually works remains undiscovered :)

Comment: I added an update.

Comment: It's a Kivy app using XCamera widget. Firstly I use front camera and then I switch to the rear one. When the app switches to rear camera it throws this error about conflicting process. I'm presuming it's because front camera process hasn't finished when switching.

Comment: @ThomasWeller  Well, I'm removing the camera widget when it's no longer needed but the process remains within the system. I'll add it to my question. There's a good chance I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: Please include a longer segment of log output - you've pasted only part of the logs from the camera service that explain why it's not letting your app use the camera.  You can also look at the camera service history logs in 'adb shell dumpsys media.camera' for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to use `self.xcamera_instance._camera._release_camera()`
It's not ideal as it forces me to use "private" method instead
of using API that interfaces with the method but I needed something
that will do the trick.